# ionic android build fail about sdk version

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, build, ionic3

I tried to

- install android sdk
- remove android platform and re add
- remove plugin
- set minSdkVersion to 19 in config.xml

but i still have a problem when building this Android project.

I ran this command
'ionic cordova build android'

and i got this error message

```
----------
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
/Users/dev_pjw/Documents/workspace/bmdevs/tgc-clinet-app/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:28:5-74 Error:
    uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:CordovaLib] /Users/dev_pjw/Documents/workspace/bmdevs/tgc-clinet-app/platforms/android/CordovaLib/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="org.apache.cordova" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:CordovaLib] /Users/dev_pjw/Documents/workspace/bmdevs/tgc-clinet-app/platforms/android/CordovaLib/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="org.apache.cordova" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

----------
```

Comment: I solved it.
i was run 'ionic cordova build'  and  i can see the plugin that does not match Android version and i delete that after android build success

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue here..but I don't follow you, what plug in do you mean?

Comment: cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-browsertab <- i remove this plugin after build success